# After reboot of CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)server ,it stopped xfs support

Tags: centos7, xfs

After reboot of CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)server ,it stopped xfs support and throws below error

> mount: unknown filesystem type 'xfs'

```
#lsmod | grep xfs
```

is not showing anything and `#modprobe xfs` is also not working .

```
#find /usr/lib/modules/$(uname -r) -name *xfs*
find: ‘/usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-957.10.1.el7.x86_64’: No such file or directory

#find /usr/lib/modules/$(uname -r) -name \*xfs\*
find: ‘/usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-957.10.1.el7.x86_64’: No such file or directory

# find /usr/lib/modules -maxdepth 1 -type d
/usr/lib/modules
/usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-1062.4.3.el7.x86_64
/usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7.x86_64
/usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64
/usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-1062.4.1.el7.x86_64
/usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-1062.7.1.el7.x86_64
```

Comment: @NasirRiley, Added result of find in question and  no,  there is no file in /etc/modprobe.d blacklisting the xfs module

Comment: The kernel release for CentOS 7.7 is currently `3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7.x86_64`. You should have at least `3.10.0-1068.#.#.el7.x86_64` but the release from `uname` is giving you `3.10.0-957.10.1.el7.x86_64` which is for CentOS 7.6. Add the output of `find /usr/lib/modules -maxdepth 1 -type d` to your question just to confirm. If that directory really isn't there, it explains why `xfs` isn't showing up. The directory for the kernel isn't in the modules directory. When booting, do one of the current versions of the kernel that I listed above show up? If so, choose one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling latest update fixed it for me.

```
# yum history undo 210
```

While doing this i got below errors,

```
warning: file /boot/vmlinuz-3.10.0-1062.4.1.el7.x86_64: remove failed: No such file or directory
warning: file /boot/symvers-3.10.0-1062.4.1.el7.x86_64.gz: remove failed: No such file or directory
warning: file /boot/config-3.10.0-1062.4.1.el7.x86_64: remove failed: No such file or directory
warning: file /boot/System.map-3.10.0-1062.4.1.el7.x86_64: remove failed: No such file or directory
warning: file /boot/.vmlinuz-3.10.0-1062.4.1.el7.x86_64.hmac: remove failed: No such file or directory
  Cleanup    : kernel.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                                           33/41
warning: file /boot/vmlinuz-3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7.x86_64: remove failed: No such file or directory
warning: file /boot/symvers-3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7.x86_64.gz: remove failed: No such file or directory
warning: file /boot/config-3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7.x86_64: remove failed: No such file or directory
warning: file /boot/System.map-3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7.x86_64: remove failed: No such file or directory
warning: file /boot/.vmlinuz-3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7.x86_64.hmac: remove failed: No such file or directory
```

Indicating coorupt files/storage . Thank you @NasirRiley